# C# Default Literal Always Returning False, .Equals()

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, c#-7.1

How can I compare a `ValueType` using a Default Literal?

I tried this, but it returns `_darkBlue.Equals(default)` always returns `false`:

```
static Color _darkBlue;

public static Color DarkBlue => _darkBlue.Equals(default) ? (_darkBlue = Color.FromHex("2980b9")) : _darkBlue;
```

Note: `Color` in this example is `Xamarin.Forms.Color`

Edit: Reproduction Sample: https://github.com/brminnick/ColorEqualsRepro

Comment: Do you want it to be a thread safe singleton?

Comment: @maccettura Good point, I hadn't considered Thread Safety! It doesn't have to be, but would you mind sharing both a thread-safe and a non-thread-safe answer? I'm curious to see both now!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? It looks like it should work, at first glance.

Comment: A struct, *by definition*, can't be a singleton.

Comment: `Color.FromHex("2980b9")` is not such an expensive operation that it's worthwhile to try to defer performing it.  Just perform it on construction of the containing object.  You'll likely spend more resources attempting to defer the execution of that operation than you will by doing the work earlier than it might be needed.

Comment: Thanks @Servy. I'm deferring it to minimize startup time for my app. This is a mobile app created using Xamarin.Forms and every millisecond I can save at startup, the better!

Comment: @BrandonMinnick If performance really matters, then there are almost certainly many thousands of things that matter more than this that you could be spending your time on to improve performance much more effectively.  If performance really matters to you, focus on the things that are actually impacting it.

Comment: can't reproduce the issue you're reporting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with `.Equals`. The compiler is interpreting `.Equals(default)` as `.Equals(default(object))`.

Changing `.Equals` to `==` fixed the problem.

```
public static Color DarkBlue => _darkBlue == default ? (_darkBlue = Color.FromHex("2980b9")) : _darkBlue;
```

Another solution is to use `.Equals(default(Color))`

```
public static Color DarkBlue => _darkBlue.Equals(default(Color)) ? (_darkBlue = Color.FromHex("2980b9")) : _darkBlue;
```

Another solution, using `Color.IsDefault`

```
public static Color DarkBlue => _darkBlue.IsDefault ? (_darkBlue = Color.FromHex("2980b9")) : _darkBlue;
```